# Generating numbers in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have an `invoice` table. It has fields `id`, `oder_id`, `user_id`, `invoice_num`, I need to increment `invoice_num` for a specific user each time a user adds information to this table. Those. for a user with `id 1` at the first `insert` it will be equal to 1, at the second `insert` it will be 2, etc., for a user with `id = 2`, it will be exactly the same at the first `insert` 1, at the second 2, etc. I use `RLS`, if there is any solution using `rls` it will be generally cool. Please tell me how can I implement this on postgresql.

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/gapless-sequence/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL sequence based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821871/postgresql-sequence-based-on-another-column) or [How to create sequence based on other column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357465/how-to-create-sequence-based-on-other-column-value)

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135437/create-unique-sequence-per-set-of-rows-sharing-the-same-foreign-key-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964